# Email deleted after database table updates in PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, database, forms

I want to update users email from a form in my php page, but after i change the email, php delete it from database, any suggestion?

```
session_start();
require_once('database.php');

if (isset($_POST['modify-profile'])) {

    $query = "UPDATE users SET email = '$_SESSION[m_email]' WHERE name ='$_SESSION[name]'";
    $check = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $check->execute();
 
    header('Location: ../profile.php');
    exit;

} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}

 <form action="php/modify-profile.php" method="POST">
              <input type="email" placeholder="Email:" name="m_email">
              <input type="submit" name="modify-profile">
            </form>
```

Comment: shouldn't your email be in the $_POST array instead of $_SESSION?

Comment: One problem with your code is that it will always echo 'ERROR" unless the form is posted.  You should remove that else critieria.  Inside the check for `$_POST['modify-profile']` you should also check `if (!empty(trim($_POST['m_email'])) { ...`  and display an error for an empty m_email.  I'd also suggest using [filter_var](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) to check that the email submitted is in at least valid format, and issue an error otherwise.